# IP rules misconfigured, lost access to server

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall

I have to give my IP rule like,

DROP if source is not from 127.0.0.1 AND destination is 9200

But unfortunately, I gave it like,

DROP if source is not from 127.0.0.1
(missed the port)

So I lost communication with server.
Can some help me how to fix this, like how to flush the existing IP rules ?
(I dont have access to server now)

Thank you.

Comment: You're going to either need to reboot the server or get OOB console access to it.

Comment: Yes, let me give a try

Comment: I got this done after asking my hosting service provider to turn off the iptables. Then I deleted the bad IP rule and restarted ip tables. Everything went fine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, at this point you need to have someone reboot the system. If you didn't make the change persistent it should be okay.

When I have to make changes to iptables and have no way of recovering, I put a cron job up to revert the iptables changes to the last known saved state. You can use iptables-save and then run iptables-restore in your cronjob. So it would go like this:
1. Save current running state
2. Create cronjob entry to run iptables-restore against the file you created with iptables-save
3. Make the change, verify access is still there. If not, wait until cron executes.
4. Make change permanent.

You can also use at to schedule this but I have not had the greatest luck with it.

Comment: Alternatively:  `/sbin/iptables <rule change> ; sleep 60 && service iptables restart` or `/sbin/iptables <rule change> ; sleep 60 && /sbin/iptables -F`

Comment: Better use **iptables-apply** (can be found on a wide range of distros). It will apply the ruleset in the file taken as a parameter then prompt you to confirm it works and automatically revert it if you don't.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your query you can flush the iptables content using the below commands.

Command to flush the IP tables

```
sudo iptables -F
```

Command to restore the iptables rule-set that was saved with the iptables-save command

```
iptables-restore [-c] [-n]
```

Comment: That will only flush the filter table rules. Depending on what he had this may not be sufficient.

Comment: I lost access to server (no ssh), so this wont work.